# Magento 2: Error on checkout "Logged in customer Checkout getting No such entity with orderId =" for logged in customer

Tags: checkout, magento2.3.2

I'm using a Magento 2.3.2 in our production site.

But I don't know why when I try to place an order with an existing user, I am getting No such entity with orderId=. When I buy something as a guest, there isn't any problem.

How can I fix it?

[image: no such entity with orderId =]

When I check the error in Chrome console, I get the following:

POST http://XXXX/rest/en/V1/carts/mine/payment-information 400 (Bad Request)

[image]

Comment: Try disabling other extensions to see if they are impacting here. Especially the ones with Plugins and Observers for order related classes and events.

Comment: Hi Nidheesh, I've only one plugin which can be related to orders. Thats the SendCloud plugin, SendCloud is our transport-broker. I’ve disabled and tested but with no positive results. Is it needed to uninstall the extension to test it? Do you have other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: May this answer can help. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/369761/109248

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people who also get this problem, the problem was solved months ago by an external debugger / Magento specialist. The problem was Mageplaza_SameOrderNumber extension. When disabled the order gets successfully created.